# Python method missing an argument but all seems to be there

Tags: python, python-3.x

What i'm trying to do is run a piece of code that did work at one time, but when i loaded up the project the captcha solving function is saying i'm missing an argument in a function but i don't see where.

**Code:**

This piece of code:

```
            elif action_to_take == "RECAPTCHA_V2":
                selenium_field = self.execute_recaptcha_v2_solver(captcha_key, url_or_field_identifier)
                self.write_to_debug_file("--> SOLVING RECAPTCHA V2 ...", _filename)
```

Then executes:

```
    # this function executes the ReCaptcha solver ...
    def execute_recaptcha_v2_solver(self, api_key, url_or_field_identifier):
        solve_recaptcha_v2 = CaptchaReCaptchaSolver.solve_recaptcha(api_key,
                                                                    self.extract_data_site_key(self.driver.page_source),
                                                                    url_or_field_identifier)
        javascript_code = 'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "{}"'.format(solve_recaptcha_v2)
        return self.driver.execute_script(javascript_code)
```

Which runs the Class:

```
class CaptchaReCaptchaSolver(object):

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def solve_recaptcha(self, _captcha_api_key, _site_key, _url):
        print(_captcha_api_key, _site_key, _url)
        """ this function solves recaptcha using 2captcha.com """
        try:

            # p = '127.0.0.1:6969'
            # p = {'http': 'http://' + p, 'https': 'https://' + p}

            # send off requests ...
            s = requests.Session()
            cap_id = s.post('http://2captcha.com/in.php?key={}&method=userrecaptcha&googlekey={}&pageurl={}'.format(
                _captcha_api_key, _site_key, _url)).text.split('|')[1]
            rec_an = s.get("http://2captcha.com/res.php?key={}&action=get&id={}".format(_captcha_api_key, cap_id)).text

            # tell us what is going on ...
            print("--> ReCAPTCHA V2 SOLVING")
            print("--> SOLVING ...")
            while "CAPTCHA_NOT_READY" in rec_an:
                sleep(5)
                rec_an = s.get("http://2captcha.com/res.php?key={}&action=get&id={}".format(_captcha_api_key, cap_id)).text

            rec_an = rec_an.split('|')[1]

            # solved ...
            print("--> " + rec_an)
            print("--> SOLVED ...")
            print("--> ReCAPTCHA V2 RESPONSE")

            # payload ...
            payload = {'key': 'value', 'gresponse': rec_an}
            s.post(_url, payload)

            # return ReCaptcha answer ...
            return rec_an

        except Exception as e:
            print("2CAPTCHA.COM [ReCAPTCHA] ERROR: ", e)
```

The error is:

```
LINE 222 "selenium_field = self.execute_recaptcha_v2_solver(captcha_key, url_or_field_identifier)"): solve_recaptcha() missing 1 required positional argument: '_url'
```

The class method `solve_recaptcha()` is missing an argument it is saying, but i have printed them out and they are all there, am i missing something obvious? i cannot see what the issue could be, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're calling an instance method on the class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice here... `CaptchaReCaptchaSolver.solve_recaptcha` this is how you would call a static class member not an instance.  Since the method's first param is `self` then it requires the function be called on an instance of the object.

This should fix.
    `CaptchaReCaptchaSolver().solve_recaptch(...`

Now your final code is

```
# this function executes the ReCaptcha solver ...
def execute_recaptcha_v2_solver(self, api_key, url_or_field_identifier):
    solve_recaptcha_v2 = CaptchaReCaptchaSolver().solve_recaptcha(api_key,
                                                                self.extract_data_site_key(self.driver.page_source),
                                                                url_or_field_identifier)
    javascript_code = 'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "{}"'.format(solve_recaptcha_v2)
    return self.driver.execute_script(javascript_code)
```

Comment: argh thank you! it's always the smallest things that get you!